# Spring Boot -1.5.3.Release Version - Enabled with Security Features?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I use Spring Boot - 1.5.3.Release Version for my project. Simply tested my demo application with **Actuator** and **Dev-tools plugin** from [spring boot initializer site](https://start.spring.io/). (Hence I no longer needed to share my POM, as it is default).When I launch my application and try to hit the metrics End Point URL, I get this 401 Unauthorized status (image given below).
 
[image: Metrics]

**Following Options Tried to Bypass this exception**

- I excluded the SecurityAutoConfiguration on my main Class.

  ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
  public class MainConfig {
  ```

But the above option didn't work.

- When I downgrade my **Spring-Boot - 1.4.6.RELEASE Version**, I **didn't** get the UnAuthorized Exception. My Application worked like a charm :-)

**Questions**

- Is there any Specific Security Enhancements have been made in the latest release of Spring-Boot (1.5.3.RELEASE Version)?
- If at all any enhancements made, let know the community on how to bypass such kind of exceptions?
- I also, noticed that when using Spring-boot (1.5.3.RELEASE) it doesn't show any exceptions on startup, even though I have multiple main program in my IDE build path. Is that also an enhancement is spring-boot (1.5.3.RELEASE) version?

Kindly clarify.

Comment: Have you actually read [the docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#actuator-security) on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Spring Boot 1.5 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.5-Release-Notes#actuator-security):

> If you’re upgrading a Spring Boot 1.4 application that doesn’t have dependency on Spring Security **and** you wish to retain open access to your sensitive endpoints you’ll need to set `management.security.enabled` to `false`.